# How to associate an object with the quantity of that object

Tags: java

I am working on a *Java* application and came across a general implementation/meta question and wanted to reach out for suggestions.

I am looking to associate a Java object with a quantity. The java object is complex. In my case, it is a serializable object that represents JSON data from a 3rd party API. I am looking to associate a quantity with this complex Java object.

As this may be something that is easier to understand with an example, here is one. Say I have a `Car` class that is used to represent a car. It contains all the details of what make a car a car and is a general form that can be used to communicate over an API. Say I am making an inventory app for a dealership. The dealership would want to know how many of each `Car` they have. Hence the need for the association.

## Ideas

There are some ways I can think of the do this.

#### Class it out

One idea would be to create classes that capture this association. One could have an `InventoryEntry` class that contains a `Car` and a quantity. Your dealerships inventory would then consist of a `List` of `InventoryEntry` objects.

#### Arrays

One can also implement this association via an Array mechanism. This can be done by creating an `ArrayList<Car>` for the cars and an `ArrayList<Integer>` for the quantity. The index for each list would be used to associate the two.

Would you recommend one of these method or some other implementation?

Comment: How about `HashMap`?

Comment: Use a `Map` where a `Car` object is the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ArrayList makes it a little bit easier to start out, but if you are going to maintaining and extending this application, creating a custom class will save you a lot of time in the long run. The reason is that it would be difficult to change the ArrayList class. Yes, you could subclass the arraylist class, and override the methods that you need to, but that is making more work for yourself.

For the basic scenario that you gave, creating a CarInventory class could be extended for new behavior. The new class could just wrap a basic ArrayList or HashMap implementation, but being able to extend your application for long term maintainability is important.